# Library to write interactive geometry applets with Python

Tags: python, gui, data-visualization

I am interested in writing interactive programs in computational geometry using Python. Here are a couple of nice examples to illustrate what I have in mind.

1. [This](https://youtu.be/qraL4nIfkbI?t=57) part in the Youtube video
2. [Angles in a kite](http://www.saltire.com/HTML5/Basic%20Geometry/Angles%20in%20a%20Particular%20Kite.html)
3. [Similar Triangles](http://www.saltire.com/HTML5/Basic%20Geometry/Similar%20Triangles.html)

I want to prototype several heuristics for a research problem I am working on. The following example would be a typical use-case for me.

Once the program runs, a GUI window opens up into which a user can "mouse"
in his/her points in the two dimensional plane using mouse-clicks. The user can also move these points to a different position by clicking 
these points.

I would then like to have several buttons available below to experiment with, say, different convex-hull algorithms -- Each button would run and animate different convex-hull algorithm on the same set of points.

Scipy, Numpy and the CGAL Python bindings contain the necessary algorithmic ingredients but they do not have ***any*** visualization tools. I know MATPLOTLIB is a great plotting tool, but AFAIK it cannot do interactive animations of the types above.

I know I would have to base my GUI program on GUI toolkits using WxPython 
or PyQT. But from what I know, these libraries only provide the GUI part of drawing windows, 
mouse-clicks, status bars, menu bars etc. -- nothing to draw or handle geometric objects like points, segments, lines, circles, splines etc.

I am guessing some kind of "geometry manager / app" would have to be "embedded" inside a wxPython frame with which the user can interact. 
Every mouse-click should then translate into a pair/triple of real numbers depending on the dimension of the problem.

But I am not sure, since I have never done GUI programming. The only 
animations I have done are non-interactive by using ffmpeg to stitch 
together my `.png` plot output files from matplotlib at successive time-steps.

**Any recommendations for a good mature library to do this?  **